# Aug cu issue_sp 2010

Tags: service-application

I tried installed Aug cu 2012 in my SP2010 sp1 farm but i cannot install. It prompts as "expected version of the product, when the system was not found". And i have checked the Turkish language pack SP1 is not installed (Note: Turkish language pack installed properly).I cannot install Turkish language pack sp1. Since the sp1 exe itself issue.

We found one command to resolve this issue==> Package.Bypass.Detection.Check=1.   If i use this command. Is there get chance to farm will affect ?

Please, can you tell me any alternate solution to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

There is a regression in the August 2012 CU its one to avoid - June 2012 is probably you're best bet. http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/August2012CU.aspx

But guessing you're alread committed to this install and its a production environment perhaps? If so you're probably desperate enough to try that flag and throw caution to the wind.